# Specify array as a tuple

Tags: typescript, tuples

For instance, I have an abstract class:

```
type Tuple = [string, number]

abstract class SomeAbstractClass {
    tuples: Tuple[]
}
```

But when I want to implement this class

```
class SomeConcreteClass implements SomeAbstractClass {
    public tuples = [
        ['hello', 3],
        ['world', 4]
    ]
}
```

I am getting an error '`(string | number)[][] is not assignable to Tuple[]`'.
How to tell Typescript that the array I provided actually satisfies the interface?

Comment: Give each array a type? `public tuples = [ <Tuple>['hello', 3], <Tuple>['world', 4] ];`

Comment: Maybe it will work out, but it's a coercion, and Typescript suggests to convert it to 'unknown' first. This is a massive construction and I'd like to avoid that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use explicit type:

```js
type Tuple = [string, number]

abstract class SomeAbstractClass {
    tuples: Tuple[] = null as any
}

class SomeConcreteClass implements SomeAbstractClass {
    public tuples: Tuple[] = [
        ['hello', 3],
        ['world', 4]
    ]
}
```

`SomeConcreteClass` `tuples` property is mutable, hence TypeScript is unsure whehter it is assignable to abstract class tuples or not